# Redis php extension for php 8.2 on centos 7

Tags: php, redis, centos7

I've virtual machine running on centos 7, Apache with php8.2
I need to install redis and redis php extension on the mentioned vm.

The service is up and running but the php extension is not exist even after i installed it using below commands.

yum install php82-php-pecl-redis6.x86_64
but didn't find it in phpinfo  or in php -m command

Also i get this error:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: igbinary_serialize), /usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Can someone HELP